# Как перенести слово листья

Tags: морфемика, перенос

Учитель в школе говорит, что нельзя отделять одну букву от корня. Нет слога стья.

Answer (score 2):

См. ответ [**справочной службы русского языка Грамоты.ру**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=294048) на аналогичный вопрос:

> Правильные переносы: ***ли-стья*** и ***лис-тья***.

---

**P.S.**

> Учитель в школе говорит, что нельзя отделять одну букву от корня.

Правила о том, что нельзя отделять **последнюю** букву от корня, не существовало раньше, не существует сейчас. Вот как подходящее к разбираемому нами случаю правило сформулировано в [**«Полном академическом справочнике»**](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=97#pp97) под ред. Лопатина:

> **§ 217.** Группа неодинаковых согласных букв в середине слова, входящих в корень или образующих стык корня и суффикса, может быть разбита переносом любым образом, напр.: *се-стра, сес-тра* и *сест-ра; це-нтральный, цен-тральный* и *цент-ральный; ро-ждение* и *рож-дение; де-тство, дет-ство, детс-тво* и *детст-во; шу-мный и шум-ный.*

Answer (score 0):

В учебнике 2 класса есть правило, запрещающее переносить слова, состоящие из двух слогов, один из которых — из одной буквы, например: *язык*, *иней*, *обувь*.